# Designing an interface similar to Instagram and Facebook application

Tags: user-interface, meteor, reactjs

I'm just starting out with using Meteor, and something I've been trying to figure out but have come up short is exactly how to create an interface similar to Facebook and Instagram. What I want is a navigation placed at the bottom of my app with five buttons for the user to navigate to different features of the app.

For example, Instagram has Home, Explore, Upload, Activity, and User Profile. Similarly, Facebook has News Feed, Requests, Messenger, Notifications, and More.

Thank you in advance for any help you could offer.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you can achieve something like this just using css. Giving an element the style `position: fixed` will essentially "fix" an element to a position on the screen. You can then use `bottom: 0` to make the element "stick" to the bottom of the screen and have the rest of your content flow underneath this component.